# Kubernetes + ELK : Connecting kibana to elasticsearch service

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I have Elasticsearch POD + SERVICE, and Kibana POD + SERVICE. I'm trying to connect my Kibana POD to Elasticsearch service, but I get connection errors.

This is my yaml of Kibaba POD:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: kibana
    image: kibana:6.6.1
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "bin/kibana --elasticsearch.url='elasticsearch-service:9200'"]
```

I get the following errors:

```
 FATAL  ValidationError: child "elasticsearch" fails because [child "hosts" fails because [single value of "hosts" fails because ["hosts" must be a valid uri with a scheme matching the http|https pattern]]]
```

From what I understand, I get error because the elasticsearch.url, doesn't start with http/https. So I tried to run         `args: ["-c", "bin/kibana --elasticsearch.url='http://elasticsearch-service:9200'"]`, but I get also connection errors (I think because service is not meant to be pointed with http/https).

This is the yaml of elasticsearch service (which works well):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: serving
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 9300
    name: node2node
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

With other PODs I could connect with elasticsearch-service:9200, but Kibana demends http/https. How can I make them connect?

Comment: Could you share the errors you get when you pass a full URI to kibana? Elasticsearch uses http on port 9200 so it should work. Maybe try removing the single quotes around the Uri

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by adding:

```
env:
  - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
    value: "http://elasticsearch-service:9200"
  - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
    value: "9200"
  - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
    value: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kibana-service:5601/proxy
  - name: SERVER_HOST
    value: "0.0.0.0"
```

What really solved is the SERVER_BASEPATH env.

Answer (score 0):

Can you hit elasticsearch service from Kibana pod.
Remove single quite around elasticsearch service. It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html):

the docker-compose version is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch.example.org
```

You just convert it to kubernetes service either manually or using kompose tool and run it.

Or you can try to plugin the env variable into your existing file and remove the elasticsearch url option from ur command.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch.example.org
```

OR If you just name your elasticsearch service as elasticsearch , it should work without passing anything because the default value is:

```
http://elasticsearch:9200
```

example with your existing service name:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
    env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: "http://elasticsearch-service:9200"
```

Comment: didn't work. I get the following errors:       {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-09T18:24:22Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-09T18:24:22Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}

Comment: You will see these msgs for a while because elasticsearch may not be up when kibana starts , make sure elastic search is running already , this is something that needs troubleshooting

Comment: Also make sure you can succeffuly access the elasticsearch url that u are using in kibana config.  maybe you need to expose it as kubernetes service

Answer (score -1):

Don't use switch `--elasticsearch.url` use environment variable ELASTICSEARCH_URL instead.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: kibana
    image: kibana:6.6.1
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "bin/kibana"]
    env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
      value: "http://elasticsearch-service:9200"
```

I suggest you also, read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961304/1573395) in another thread for more detailed k8s DNS explanation.